# Run a web service request in separate thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, iis

On a C# XML Web Service class, is it possible to get IIS to lauch each client request in a separate thread... I need to add in some code from a separate library that needs eacj

```
public class FlightOperationsService : WebService
{
    public string SayHello()
    {
        return (ExternalLibary.RunRequest()); // Must be in separate thread
    }
}
```

In the case where multiple clients attach, each request needs to be run in separate thread but it appears IIS or the WebService class uses that same thread which is causing issues with the external library

Comment: A good reference for you, if you can't use the async/await features of C# 5.0: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385165/parallelasync-tasks-using-web-service-to-avoid-threads

Comment: I should add that the main reason is tha external library process has lots of "batching up" and therefore needs to separate out different requests to ensure the "batching" does not cross-contaminate.

Comment: I've taken the easy route for the moment in spawning a new thread in the web service, as suggested by Ela, which will then execute the external process as this appears to be doing the trick right now.

I know there are risks with this approach, but for now, its a quick tactucal solution until such time as I can convert the whole Web service into WCF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you work with .net4.5 try implement asyn/await and check if this solves your issues.
Otherwise you can create a new thread from System.Threading.

Be aware that creating new threads costs lots of resources on the server! If you have tons of client connections, this isn't appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
but this is not your scenario, since you need to return the string directly in the function. the only way to change your code is to use await / async in .net 4.5, otherwise you need to use some async io method. which means you need to pass in a context, and fill the value in the context later.
say

```
public IAsyncResult SayHello(AsyncContext context)
{
     // start a new async operation and return the IAsyncResult
}

void RealWork(AsyncContext context)
{
    context.SetValue("some thing");
}
```

it's just a prototype, the real word is much harder. but i have a suggestion to try procedure programming here, [you can get the sample and binary here, http://procedure.codeplex.com/](http://procedure.codeplex.com/). as the owner of the project, sorry, i have made an ad for myself ..., feel free to drop me a message if you need some introduction or further suggestion.

P.S. whether needs to handle the request in a separated thread depends on if you have operations other than memory / processor, say network / harddisk IO